# Is there any CMOS chip/battery in android?

Tags: android, mobile, hardware, battery, android-hardware

I search on google and I dint find anything that relates CMOS chip/battery in android.
Here is my question :
Is there any CMOS chip/Battery in android ?

I didn't find anything on this subject.

Thank you guys !

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes Subir, Its not programming question as above tags relates to hardware and android etc. Actually I am looking for cmos related operation for my new app. Please bear it.

Comment: In case you don't know, there's a sister site about Android on [android.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not to say that it's "In-android"  android hardware can be as loosely defined as "can run the software of android".  It doesn't particularly need CMOS chips to be an android.

That being said certain developers of the phone do indeed have CMOS. (Samsung Galaxy, a couple Sony phones, ect.)